# Pass URL parameters with URL forwarding

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url-parameters, forwarding

I am a novice developer, started coding a few months back,

only familiar with : HTML/JS/CSS & NODE/Express.js for server side..

**PROJECT DETAILS**

I'm working on ---
Developing a social platform just like there are Insta & FB, called **letsgrow**.

To make the user experience better & specific, I have purchased several domains, for different Sources like : `letsgrow.uk`, `letsgrow.es`, `letsgrow.in` etc.

after entering the url, thet are all redirected to one platform : `letsgrow.web.app`

Currently, I'm using firebase for hosting this platform.

**PROBLEM**

With the domain provider, I'm only getting the "Forward this Domain to" option, and no other controls, which is *Redirect(HTTP 301 forwarding)*

How do I pass URL params from the source domains to the redirected one
EXAMPLE :
`letsgrow.uk/?post=ab123`  to `letsgrow.web.app/?post=ab123`

Comment: What is happening currently? Are the query params getting dropped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do that in all the websites you want to redirect. And also turn off your HTTP forwarding as the javascript will automatically forward you to that website along with your parameters!

```js
// https://letsgrow.in/
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var urlParam = currentUrl.substring(20);
var newLink = 'https://letsgrow.web.app/'+urlParam;
window.onload=function(){
  window.location.replace(newLink)
}
```

Comment: Hi @HackNetAyush, thanks for your answer...

But with the domains, I don't have the hosting to put the js on..

I only own the Domains, and no hosting on them..

Comment: You can use replit.com <for free project hosting> and then you can make an HTML/CSS/JS project and then you just paste this js code in script.js file and then you have to connect your domain to this project by clicking on the pencil icon near the URL of the website just above the website display section in replit, then add a CNAME to the domain you can add it in DNS Management of your domain. Thank You!